# htaccess IfModule conditional fails

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have a basic .htaccess file. 
If I leave it empty the page loads correctly.
If I have a conditional statement in there (e.g.:)

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    #Intentionally left blank
</IfModule>
```

I get a 500 error.

So even though the mod_filter exists and is loaded it dies. Even though there is nothing in the IfModule statement.

It's almost as if the `<IfModule>` statement itself isn't working.

This is on 32bit WAMP on Windows.

I have other sites running locally that do have full htaccess files, and they work, but this one just won't play!

Any one seen this before?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a corrupted file. Recreating the file worked.

Answer (score 3):

Remove a space after `mod_filter.c` :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the space as shown below after `mod_filter.c`

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
#Intentionally left blank
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks but I had tried that. Removing the space still gives the error.

Comment: I think you might have spotted the issue as I think it might have been a corrupted file. I created a new one and it all worked. Very odd! Thanks for your help :)